# running php script in filezilla

Tags: php, filezilla

I am using fileZilla ftp server and trying to run my php scipt. Below code to call b.php is not working. I am new to filezilla so let me know if any configuration required to run this code. I am calling b.php from a.php and both of them are in same folder.

```
 <?php
   header("Location: b.php");
 ?>
```

Comment: Filezilla is just an FTP file manipulation tool (uploading, downloading, deleting.. sort of FTP File Manager or File Server). It has **nothing to do with php code working or not**. For php you need a web server like Apache or something. Perhaps you could mention what kind of error are you getting? I assume that above code is from a.php For the given code, there should be no problem in getting this code executed successfully.

Answer (score 1):

It will not work like that. You can run PHP file via terminal:

```
$ php -f file.php
```

Or you can make it executable with `$ chmod +x file.php`, add `#!/usr/bin/env php` on top of file and, finally, you run like that:

```
$ ./file.php
```

Or just access it in browser if you have Web Server configured and running.

Answer (score 0):

This code may help you...

Try to write like this

```
<?php

    header('Location: b.php');
    exit();
?>
```